# Getting the project base path in a yeoman generator

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I have updated the yeoman generator dependency from 0.18.10 to 0.20.3.
I have updated the deprecated `this.dest` to `this.destinationRoot()`

I am now having issues with the generator when it comes to getting the base path of the project, so that I can copy files from one location to another.
I have created a function to put the paths together, this then passes to another function which excludes some files from being copied over.

Here is the function I getting the error with

```
// Copy Bower files to another directory
var copyBowerFiles = function (component, to, exclude) {
  var base = this.destinationRoot(),
      publicDir = base + '/' + this.publicDir,
      publicAssetsDir = publicDir + '/assets',
      bowerComponentsDir = publicAssetsDir + '/bower_components',
      bower,
      from;

  to = (base + '/' + to || publicAssetsDir);
  from = bowerComponentsDir + '/' + component;

  //this.dest.copy(from, to);
  this.bulkDirectory(from, copyDestPathPartial.call(this, to, exclude));
};
```

This is being called in the end function:

```
end: function () {
    this.installDependencies({
        callback: function () {
            copyBowerFiles.call('jam', this.publicDir, excludeJamFiles);
        }.bind(this)
    });
}
```

I get the error message:

```
var base = this.destinationRoot(),
                ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I have also tried sourceRoot()

I would like to update my generator to work with the latest version of the generator. Any help getting this working would be great.

Also do you still have to pass `this` as the first parameter when calling a function?

**EDIT:**
Here is the copyDestPathPartial function

```
// Copy destination path partial
var copyDestPathPartial = function (to, exclude) {
  exclude = exclude || [];

  return function (abs, root, sub, file) {
    if (!_.contains(exclude, file) && ! _.contains(exclude, sub)) {
      this.copy(abs, to + '/' + (sub || '') + '/' + file);
    }
  }.bind(this.destinationRoot());
};
```

When I use `this` in the copyBowerFiles function I get another error message which says when I call this function:

```
throw new TypeError('Arguments to path.resolve must be strings');
```

Is the `copyDestPathPartial` function not outputting a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only a JavaScript error, `this` inside `copyBowerFiles` is not what you think it is.

With the code you wrote, `this` is equal to `jam`.

So here you'd want: `copyBowerFiles.call(this, 'jam', this.publicDir, excludeJamFiles);`. As the first argument to call is the `this` value. See documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

That being said, assigning random `this` value is very dirty and super hard to maintain. Why not making `copyBowerFiles` a prototype method?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I understand a little better now. I have added 'this' before any parameter, I am not getting another issues, probably related to something different than this original issue, but maybe you could let me know what the issue may be. Thanks